# FB Publish Javascript & Site URL local

Tags: facebook

Please the pardon long explanation of my question. Conceptually, the issue is the same whether it is run on a browser or in Android webview.

1. I am making an app using HTML, CSS and JS which will be deployed on Android in webview.
2. All the HTML files are stored within the asset folder, and no file is read from my website.
3. In my app I have a SHARE button, which, when clicked, will provide a POST TO WALL window.

Issues:

1. I am registering my app on FB, and I am confused as in what should I write in the SITE URL.
2. As far as I have understood FB registers an app against a web URL say www.test.com.
3. Hence my FB initiate and publish functions should be in a file which is accessible from www.test.com.
4. But the problem is that the SHARE button is shown on the page which is accessed locally from my asset folder.

Questions:

1. How can I access FB init and publish functions locally?
2. What domain should I mentioned in SITE URL which will give me access to locally stored FB functions?